# How to use C++ function in android aar file

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, aar

I build a library and pack it into an `aar` file. I import the `aar` file to my project. I can access the Java class in the `aar` file without problem, but I can't figure how to access the library's `native-lib.cpp` functions in my project's `native-lib.cpp`.